# An idiom or proverb to describe the ability to identify the best one when given a plethora of choices

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

I'm looking for an idiom or proverb that emphasise the *availability of choices* and the *ability to identify the best/correct one*. The ability is the result of experience, skills and knowledge.

For instance

> With a plethora of tools in the market, a seasoned craftsman is able to quickly assemble a right set of tools to solve a particular problem. A less experienced craftsman may fail to identify the right tools to solve the problem with the same level of efficiency.

> With that many selection of hair products in the market, an experienced hairstylist can quickly distinguish the better quality products from the mediocre ones.

> An experienced person will be able to identify which are the time-wasting activities while an inexperienced person may have to go through each one of them to find out.

Comment: 'Having a knack for something' might be a good idiom. It means being skillful in doing something. E.g. She has a knack for the piano

Comment: *Finding the needle in the haystack* might be as good as it gets. It's not that good, though. There's also *rainmaker*.

Comment: If you add a sample sentence with a blank where the answer goes, you will likely get more responses.

Comment: Isn't 'discerning'? But it is not a saying, but a word.

Answer (score -1):

I think  we  can say somebody  has  the  knack  of choosing    or  the  ability  to  choose *the  pick  of  the bunch*.

> The  pick of  the  bunch  means  the  best  in the  group.

Here  is  the  link  which  helps.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20pick%20of%20the%20bunch

Answer (score -1):

**head and shoulders above (someone or something)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/head+and+shoulders+above+%5Bthe+others+rest+etc.%5D) idiom

> Significantly better than someone or something.

As in:

***Head and shoulders above*** all the other applicants, X is the ideal candidate.